# Running Apache and PHP server on OS X Mavericks

Tags: mac

After updating Mac OX Snow Leopard to OSX Mavericks I am not able to run apache server on my mac (**note : using already install apache server for mac**)

is there any way to get it fix without reinstalling?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few research

I had trouble with my local sites working after updating to Mavericks and what I had to do was

```
Step 1

Open Finder 
      GO > GO To Folder and type (/private/etc/apache2)

and delete httpd.conf and then rename httpd.conf.pre-update back to httpd.conf 

Step 2
 Finder 
      GO > GO To Folder and type ( /private/etc )
 delete php.ini and then rename php.ini.5.2-previous back to php.ini
```

after all that just restart your apache server

```
Open Terminal and Type sudo apachectl restart
```

You are all set now.
Open safari and type local host you should see its working.

Cheers hope that helps